# Use previously registered telephone number in Telegram

Tags: telegram

(Telegram is a chat service with an open API, their official web client can be found here https://web.telegram.org/#/login)

I'm in possession of a telephone number that has previously been used by someone else to register an account with Telegram. Without infringing on this person's privacy, I would like to re-register the number with Telegram for my own use.

Telegram accounts can be deactivated (https://my.telegram.org/auth?to=deactivate) by requesting a token which is send to a Telegram client. The straight forward solution would be to sign in using an SMS token sent by Telegram and then request a termination token. However, this would also give me insight into any conversations of the previous user of this number.

Is there a way to re-register this number without violating the previous user their privacy?

Comment: That's probably something you should direct to Telegram directly.

Comment: Telegram accounts gets self-destructed after 6 months inactivity by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted the Telegram service team directly. Their suggestion was to contact the previous owner of the number to change the telephone number associated with their account. 
Alternatively, they will be able to resolve the issue if the first approach does not work out.